# Byobu - disable in Gnome Terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, byobu

I like Byobu but I want use it in virtual console only (ctrl+alt+fx). How to disable Byobu in Gnome Terminal? Byobu is enabled via .profile file.

Answer (score 0):

`Byobu` does have such setting to be launched in automatically in virtual consoles , aka `tty` . You have to login to any `tty` , launch `byobu` and then press <kbd>F9</kbd> to toggle launching at login

[image]

However, personally I'd opt in for a scripting method, where you create a function at the top of the `.bashrc`

```
function testTTY
{
  isTTY=$(tty | awk '{if ($0~/\/dev\/tty.*/) {print "true"}else{print "false"}}')

  if [ $isTTY == "true" ]; then
    byobu
  fi
}
```

And call that function somewhere at the bottom of the `.bashrc`

Also, examine, your `.profile` to remove any other automatic launching of byobu in gui terminals

Comment: Ok it's working but gnome-terminal is still intercepted by byobu http://image.qkiz.pl/di/F73M/Obszar_1_029.png
I have Gnome Terminal icon on Unity launcher. When I run Gnome Terminal new icon of Byobu is appeared.
http://image.qkiz.pl/di/ZRPM/Zaznaczenie_030.png
I want to only one icon to be appeared - Gnome Terminal.